# Keras giving error - ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (10000, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have dataset of 28x28 pictures. Datapoints array `x` has shape `(10000, 28, 28)`, labels array `y` has shape `(10000,)`.
The following code:

```py
x = x.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(8, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
    Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
model.fit(x, y, epochs=5) #error
```

gives:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (10000, 1)
```

`model.summary()` output:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 8)         80        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 28, 28, 64)        576       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 28, 28, 64)        4160      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 28, 28, 10)        650       
=================================================================
Total params: 5,466
Trainable params: 5,466
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: You should add a `Flatten` layer after convolutions _and one-hot encode your `y`_

Comment: They are using `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` which requires integer targets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to add `Flatten()` layer (`keras.layers.Flatten()`):

```py
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(8, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your output is 3-dimensional, while your target is one-dimensional. You are likely missing a `Flatten` layer after the `Con2D` layer, which will reduce the output of the convolution to a single dimension:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Dense, Flatten

# Fake data
import numpy as np
x = np.ones((10000, 28, 28))
y = np.ones((10000,))

x = x.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(8, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", activation="relu", input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(64, activation="relu"),
    Dense(64, activation="relu"),
    Dense(10, activation="softmax")
])

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

model.summary()
model.fit(x, y, epochs=1)
```

Then, the dimensions are correct:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 8)         80        
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 6272)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 64)                401472    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 64)                4160      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 10)                650       
=================================================================
Total params: 406,362
Trainable params: 406,362
Non-trainable params: 0
```